# How can I map a new array from a specific (known) pattern?

Tags: ruby, arrays, design-patterns, iteration

*Generally*, how can you determine how to iterate through an array based on a known pattern?

*Specifically*, this is the pattern I would like to iterate through, returning an array of arrays: (Each digit is an index value of the original array: [0, 1, 2, 3])

> 0
>
> 0,1
>
> 0,1,2
>
> 0,1,2,3
>
> 1
>
> 1,2
>
> 1,2,3
>
> 2
>
> 2,3
>
> 3

Comment: Can you show a example of what you want to do ?

Comment: Previous poster @SimonMayer got the gist of what I was aiming for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another more concise alternative:

```
a.size.times { |i| (a.size - i).times { |j| p a[i..j+i] } }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = [0,1,2,3]
main_array = []

arr.each_index{|i|
  arr.each_index{|j|
    if i <= j
      a = arr[i..j]
      main_array.push(a)
    end
  }
}
p main_array
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do the trick, but _how_ did you come to that solution? Is there a stripped down way of thinking through pattern iterations like this? Can a for loop be simplified to a math problem?

Comment: It is basically mathematical. I could see that your pattern has two loops: one to iterate through and determine the first part of the array; another (contained within) to iterate through and determine the length of each array.
In terms of method, I suppose I solved it in the same order. First to get the start point `i`.  Next I looked at how I start the array at `i` and slice it to an increasing length `j`.